# Can't drop constraint for table in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have oracle 11g database.
So, in the past I have uniq-constraint for table User on name and surname filed, so
my table was

```
id     name    surname     age    position
```

and constraint:

```
alter table User add constraint UK8ut91db3xdtls2x61e63iwym4 unique (name, surname);
```

But now, I need to remove this constraint, so name and surname must be not unique.
I drop this constraint by script from base:

```
  alter table ORGANIZATION.USER drop constraint UK8UT91DB3XDTLS2X61E63IWYM4
```

and this constraint dropped:

```
SELECT * FROM all_constraints WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME='UK8UT91DB3XDTLS2X61E63IWYM4'
```

last script returns nothing.

But, If I try to insert couple rows with same name and surname, but with different id's - there is error

```
INSERT INTO ORGANIZATION.USER(id, name, surname, age, position) VALUES (111-222, 'Natalia', 'Solzhenizina', 22, 'consultant')
Error report -
ORA-00001: нарушено ограничение уникальности  (constraint violetion on unique) (SBDATASVCS.UK8UT91DB3XDTLS2X61E63IWYM4)
```

Comment: Your table names are inconsistent.  Are you certain you're adding and droppng the constraint from the same table? Are there any triggers on the table you're inserting data into?

Comment: could you add the output from the query  SELECT * FROM all_constraints WHERE  table_name = 'USER';

Answer (score 1):

First, that correct way to remove constraint is:

```
alter table ORGANIZATION.USER drop constraint UK8UT91DB3XDTLS2X61E63IWYM4 CASCADE
```

If you forgot use it, some other element of constraint may stay alive(unique or index)

Optionally, you can drop **unique** with same name and **Index**.

```
DROP INDEX ORGANIZATION.UK8UT91DB3XDTLS2X61E63IWYM4

alter table ORGANIZATION.USER drop UNIQUE (name, surname);
```